# C++ Compare const char* to std::string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compare a char * to a to a std::string

```
const char *s = "0@s072116\tblah\tblah\blah";
std::string id = "072116";
```

I need to compare these two, basically before the first \t and after the first 3 chars on the left.  The width of the id can vary. :(

I'm not very good at C++.  Any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

...

int main() {
    const char *s = "0@s072116\tblah\tblah\blah";
    string ss = s;
    string id = "072116";
    int found = ss.find(id);
    cout << "found is: " << found;
}
```

If `id` is a substring in `ss`, then `found` will be the position of the first occurrence of `id` in `ss`.

If `id` is not a substring in `ss`, then `found` will be a negative number.

[More examples](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) on `find`.

**Caveat:**

The code above is based on the assumption your meant *"...basically before the first \t and after the first 3 chars on the left..."* as a way to point out where the substring would be matched in this particular example.

If instead it is a requirement that must be met for all instances (i.e. `const char *s = "0@s\tblah\tblah\blah072116"` should not be matched), then the provided code sample is not sufficient.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore is there a written / unwritten policy on SO about posting full code? I see ppl do it all the time.

Comment: It depends on the context basically. If it's an assignment, you're doing more harm than good with full code.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : also, I interpret "basically before the first \t and after the first 3 chars on the left" as the OP explaining where the string would be matched in the example, not as a requirement of the problem. It's not definitive either way - but I opted to answer the question based on incomplete information (which we all have to do in practice) instead of skipping it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Just as you inferred that he's working on an assignment even though it was never explicitly stated ;)

Comment: "before the first \t and after the first 3 chars on the left" - this part was pretty clear.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I think you missed my point in that comment; but I hope not to argue - we can agree to disagree. =)

Comment: when down-votes begin to reign in with abandon because someone doesn't like *how* the question was answered rather than *whether* the question was answered within the confines of gathering all the available context provided therein, its time for me to find a new hobby outside of answering questions on SO. Then again, I don't have the luxury, nor capability, to down-vote 10,000+ questions without putting a significant perceptible dent in my rep, so I maybe I've just not been here long enough.

Comment: Thanks!  The sample code is great.  Also, just ot be clear, there are 100 ways to skin a cat when dealing with simple things in C++, like strings or time, or converting from one thing to another.

Comment: For those of us who are not from the C++ universe many time online articles lead you the wrong direction, and amounts in a big waste of time.  Its very valuable to come here and get a straightforward answer, that is the core value of this site and the people here.  Than you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *position = std::search(s, s + std::strlen(s), id.begin(), id.end());
if (*position == '\0')
    std::cout << "Not found\n";
else
    std::cout << "Found at offset " << (position - s) << '\n';
```